# CKAN not harvesting utf-8 records correctly

Tags: python, utf-8, ckan

I'm running into a problem with harvesting records containing UTF-8 encoded characters into CKAN.  Specifically, the title of the record is supposed to be "Normales climatológicas", with an accent over a lowercase "o".  I am using version 2.5.5 of CKAN with recently pulled versions of ckanext-harvest and ckanext-spatial.   I'm using the WAF harvester from ckanext-harvest.

What's interesting is that when I directly enter the text into the CKAN dataset entry form for the Title and Notes, the resulting dataset view shows the characters correctly.   Yet the dataset view for the harvested version displays the characters incorrectly.  The title of the harvested record displays as "Normales climatolÃ³gicas", which is not correct.

My current hypothesis is that the UTF-8 encoded characters may be getting interpreted by the spatial harvester as belonging to the ISO 8859-1 character set.   My evidence comes from entering the UTF-8 encoded text into this online character set decoder:

http://www.webatic.com/run/chars/charset_decoder.php

This page shows how the text is interpreted according to both UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 character sets.  The two different versions of the string are displayed.

Is this a known problem with the CKAN harvesting code, or is there some configuration option that I'm missing, or something else entirely?   I would have guessed that harvesting UTF-8 encoded characters was a priority, since CKAN is designed for an international audience.

UPDATE:

I think there is another possible explanation:  the string is double-encoded.  The logs are showing that the title string is stored in "extras" this way:  'title': u'Normales climatol\xc3\xb3gicas'.   If the unicode encoding at the start of the string weren't there, then the string prints out correctly:

```
>>> x = u'Normales climatol\xc3\xb3gicas'
>>> print(x)
Normales climatolÃ³gicas

>>> x = 'Normales climatol\xc3\xb3gicas'
>>> print(x)
Normales climatológicas
```

Is there a way I can change the spatial harvester behavior so that it stores the title string without a double-encoding?   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are many different latin character sets for which this would be this output.  I've come across a similar problem (albeit not with CKAN).  Check out python's `str.encode` builtin method, hopefully it's of use to you.